# how can i update SQL table logic

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, webforms

I have a table structured as,

```
Table 3

Fruit ID -  Foreign Key  (Primary Key of Table 1)
Crate ID -  Foreign Key  (Primary Key of Table 2)
```

Now I need to execute a query which will,

**Update** `Crate ID` **of** `Fruit ID` **if** `Fruit ID` **is already in Table, and if not then insert record in table 3 as new record.**

This is what I got in code right now,

```
private void RelateFuirtWithCrates(List<string> selectedFruitIDs, int selectedCrateID)
{

   string insertStatement = "INSERT INTO Fruit_Crate(FruitID, CrateID) Values " +
        "(@FruitID, @CrateID);";  ?? I don't think if it's right query

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString()))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertStatement, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FruitID", ????? Not sure what goes in here));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CrateID",selectedCrateID));        
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I update Crate IDs of List of Fruits in single SQL query in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539948/how-can-i-update-crate-ids-of-list-of-fruits-in-single-sql-query-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do an "upsert" with the `MERGE` syntax in SQL Server:

```
MERGE [SomeTable] AS target
USING (SELECT @FruitID, @CrateID) AS source (FruitID, CrateID)
ON (target.FruitID = source.FruitID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET CrateID = source.CrateID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
    INSERT (FruitID, CrateID)
    VALUES (source.FruitID, source.CrateID);
```

Otherwise, you can use something like:

```
update [SomeTable] set CrateID = @CrateID where FruitID = @FruitID
if @@rowcount = 0
    insert [SomeTable] (FruitID, CrateID) values (@FruitID, @CrateID)
```

Comment: @user13814 the `MERGE` syntax works well with lists, but: in terms of parameters that isn't easy. You need to look at either "table value parameters", or using some kind of "split" udf. Or just add lots of parameters.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still confused with how can I add FruitIDs as sql parameter sir, so asked another question, 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539948/how-can-i-update-crate-ids-of-list-of-fruits-in-single-sql-query-in-c-sharp

Comment: @user13814 that is actually a surprisingly difficult thing to do; I've added an example using "dapper" to one of your later questions - we specifically added some helper code to support this common, but vexing, scenario