# How can I update Crate IDs of List of Fruits in single SQL query in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, webforms, .net-2.0, sql-server-2000

In reference to my question,

[how can i update SQL table logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539315/how-can-i-update-sql-table-logic)

I want a query which will do something like this,

[image]

I my last question was confusing hence I am asking a different question.

**How can I update Crate IDs of List of Fruits in single SQL query in c#**

FruitID and CrateID are foriegn keys and will always in other tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `IN`:

```
UPDATE FRUITS
SET CRATE = 'CRATE 7'
WHERE FRUITID IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Or

```
UPDATE FRUITS
SET CRATE = 'CRATE 7'
WHERE FRUITName IN ('Mango1', 'Mango2', 'Apple 6')
```

You can also use `LIKE` to match `Mango` and `Orange` however this may update the incorrect results (Say you want Orange 199 to be updated to Crate 7 but want Orange 198 to be Crate 6)

Comment: +1, Thanks, thats more like what I was looking for, but what if table doesn't have FruitID in it sir

Comment: @user13814 - can you post your schema?

Comment: I have added table structure in earlier question sir, please check, thanks

Comment: @user13814 - from that question it looks like you have both `FruitId` and `CrateId`

Comment: Yes, but it's not important that Table 3 will have all of **Fruit IDs** or **CrateIDs** in it, as In above example "Mango 8888" isn't in table 3 already

Comment: @user13814 - you have only shown me table 3, I need to know the other tables you are using so I can help...

Comment: Sir, table structure is very complex and I am not **allowed** to play with them, I just got this table I can work on, thanks