# Can someone tell me why this SQL query not working

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, webforms, .net-2.0

I followed this answer,

[How can I supply a List<int> to a SQL parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508240/how-can-i-supply-a-listint-to-a-sql-parameter)

Please see these questions of mine for understanding scenario,

[How can I update Crate IDs of List of Fruits in single SQL query in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539948/how-can-i-update-crate-ids-of-list-of-fruits-in-single-sql-query-in-c-sharp/16539966?noredirect=1#comment23755630_16539966)

[how can i update SQL table logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539315/how-can-i-update-sql-table-logic)

**What I am trying and not working**

```
private void relate_fruit_crate(List<string> selectedFruitIDs, int selectedCrateID)
{
    string updateStatement = "UPDATE relate_fruit_crate set CrateID = @selectedCrateID where FruitID = @selectedFruitIDs";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString()))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateStatement, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@selectedCrateID", selectedCrateID.ToString()));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@selectedFruitIDs", String.Join(",",selectedFruitIDs.ToArray())));

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

My code runs without any error,

Comment: define "not working". The data does not update in database? Do you try to run in SQL server directly ?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the IN keyword in your scenario. The problem is that the `SqlCommand.Parameters` pattern does not build the query itself, but calls a stored procedure on the database:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE relate_fruit_crate set CrateID = @selectedCrateID where FruitID in(''@selectedFruitIDs'')', N'@selectedCrateID nvarchar(1),@selectedFruitIDs nvarchar(5)', @selectedCrateID = N'1', @selectedFruitIDs = N'1,2'
```

This will not work as the array is escaped.

The workaround would be to either use a normal `StringBuilder` to create the query. (Warning! SQL Injection) or to call the query for each ID separately.

Maybe there's a way to do this with the `SqlCommand.Parameters`, but I could not find one.

OLD POST::

```
string updateStatement = "UPDATE relate_fruit_crate set CrateID IN ('@selectedCrateID') where FruitID = '@selectedFruitIDs'";
```

[....]

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@selectedFruitIDs", String.Join("','",selectedFruitIDs.ToArray())));
```

and equals (=) query will only match a single value.

Comment: Yes it needs to be `In` instead of `=`, but the parameter will still end up being just one concatenated string value.

Comment: this works only if your IDs are numeric. You need to add a singlequotes to each value as [juharr points out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540951/can-someone-tell-me-why-this-sql-query-not-working/16541024#comment23757338_16541108)

Comment: But you cannot parameterize a concatenated list of strings with quotes in them as that will just escape the quotes.  I'm not sure how to accomplish this with parameters.

Comment: @krizzzn in your latest post above, you are using "=" not "In"

Comment: In the code shown you are looking for a literal `'@selectedFruitIDs'` - I doubt that is the `FruitID` of **any** of them, but is doesn't relate ***at all*** to the parameter value

Answer (score 1):

Multi-value parameter queries are a bit of a pain in TSQL. There are options like table-valued parameters, or "split" UDFs - otherwise... it is a bit tricky. You end up having to add multiple parameters (depending on the data), and change the query to suit. If I may suggest... a library like "dapper" may help you here - it is *designed* to make scenarios like this easy:

```
using Dapper; // at the top of your code file, to enable dapper
...
private void relate_fruit_crate(List<string> selectedFruitIDs, int selectedCrateID)
{
    // note the slightly unusual "in" here (no paranethesis) - that is because
    // dapper is going to do some voodoo...    
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString()))
    {
        connection.Open();
        connection.Execute(
            "UPDATE relate_fruit_crate set CrateID = @selectedCrateID where FruitID in @selectedFruitIDs",
            new { selectedFruitIDs, selectedCrateID });
    }
}
```

here "dapper" does all the work of figuring out how to express that `in` using multiple parameters, adding the correct number of parameters. It is also just much easier (in particular, look at how little work we did with commands and parameters; it handles readers nicely too).

Dapper is [freely available from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper)